# Python - 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i've got this code which takes an unsorted list and two integers and then searches to see if there's a value in the list than is higher than one of the integers and lower than the other, everytime i run it i get "'type' object is not subscriptable" which makes absolutely no sense to me as i'm a beginner... Please help.

```
def unsortedSearch(list1, i, u):
    found = False
    pos = 0
    pos2 = 0

    while pos < len(list1) and not found:
        if list[pos] < u :
            if list[pos2] > i:
                found = True
            pos2 = pos2 + 1
        pos = pos + 1
    return found

unsortedList = ['1', '3', '4', '2', '6', '9', '2', '1', '3', '7']
num1 = '3'
num2 = '5'

isItThere = unsortedSearch(unsortedList, num1, num2)

if isItThere:
    print ("There is a number between those values")
else:
    print ("There isn't a number between those values")
```

Comment: you are calling `list[pos],list[pos2]` rather than `list1[pos/list1[pos2]`

Comment: as a general best practice, avoid using `list` as the variable name... it shadows the builtin list object. guideline is always to describe what the list is IE `list_of_numbers` or `terms_to_search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `unsortedSearch` you have a parameter named `list1`, but in the body of the function it looks like you are referring to it as `list`.  So change all of your `list` with `list1` and your current problem will be solved:

```
def unsortedSearch(list1, i, u):
    found = False
    pos = 0
    pos2 = 0

    while pos < len(list1) and not found:
        if list1[pos] < u : # <--------------- fixed here
            if list1[pos2] > i: # <----------- and here
                found = True
            pos2 = pos2 + 1
        pos = pos + 1
    return found
```

Answer (score 0):

you use list[] iso list1[]. list is a type in python and as the error tells you, you cannot subscribe types

next to that, you could use list comprehension to make the code more readable

```
if [x for x in unsortedList if num1 < x < num2]:
    print("There is a number between those values")
else:
    print("There isn't a number between those values")
```

the part between *[]* is called list comprehension: basically will return a list with every if, where x is between num1 and num2.
because an empty list is false in Python, (together will None, False, 0 and "") you can use the *if* shortcut

Answer (score 0):

```
while pos < len(list1) and not found:
    if list[pos] < u :
        if list[pos2] > i:
            found = True
        pos2 = pos2 + 1
    pos = pos + 1
```

you use 'list' instead of 'list1' in your if conditions.

Revise the algorithm: if I understood well, you are looking for a value in the list between i and u. Then why do you define pos and pos2 ?

You want to check if i < list1[pos] < u, if not then go to the next item in the list.

That should be enough for you to write the code :)